# Como implementar lista circular simplesmente encadeada baseando em um lista linear simplesmente encadeada?

Tags: java, estrutura-de-dados

Olá pessoal como implementar lista circular simplesmente encadeada baseando em um lista linear simplesmente encadeada?

Método de inserção de elemento em uma determinada posição:

```
@Override
public void adiciona(E elemento, int posicao) throws Exception {
    this.validarPosicao(posicao);
    this.verificarPosicaoOcupada(posicao);
    if (posicao == 0) {
        this.adicionaInicio(elemento);
    } else {
        if (posicao == this.tamanho) {
            this.adicionaFim(elemento);
        } else {
            Celula<E> anterior = this.recuperaCelulaRecursivo(this.primeira, posicao - 1, 0);
            Celula<E> nova = new Celula<>(elemento, anterior.getProxima());
            anterior.setProxima(nova);
            this.tamanho += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Método de inserção de elemento no fim da lista:

```
@Override
public void adicionaFim(E elemento) {
    if (this.vazio()) {
        this.adicionaInicio(elemento);
    } else {
        Celula<E> nova = new Celula<>(elemento);
        this.ultima.setProxima(nova);
        this.ultima = nova;
        this.tamanho += 1;
    }
}
```

Método de inserção de elemento no início da lista:

```
@Override
public void adicionaInicio(E elemento) {
    Celula<E> nova = new Celula<>(elemento, this.primeira);
    this.primeira = nova;
    if (this.vazio()) {
        this.ultima = this.primeira;
    }
    this.tamanho += 1;
}
```

Método de remoção de elemento em uma determinada posição:

```
@Override
public void remove(int posicao) throws Exception {
    this.validarPosicao(posicao);
    this.verificarSeEstaVazio();
    this.verificarPosicaoLivre(posicao);
    if (this.vazio()) {
        this.removeInicio();
    } else {
        if (posicao == this.tamanho - 1) {
            this.removeFim();
        } else {
            Celula<E> anterior = this.recuperaCelulaRecursivo(this.primeira, posicao - 1, 0);
            Celula<E> atual = anterior.getProxima();
            Celula<E> proxima = atual.getProxima();
            anterior.setProxima(proxima);
            proxima.setElemento(anterior.getProxima().getElemento());
            this.tamanho -= 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Método de remoção de elemento no fim da lista:

```
@Override
public void removeFim() throws Exception {
    this.verificarSeEstaVazio();
    Celula<E> celulaAuxiliar = this.primeira;
    Celula<E> celulaAnterior = null;
    while (celulaAuxiliar.getProxima() != null) {
        celulaAnterior = celulaAuxiliar;
        celulaAuxiliar = celulaAuxiliar.getProxima();
    }
    Celula<E> celulaVazia = null;
    celulaAnterior.setProxima(celulaVazia);
    this.ultima = celulaAnterior;
    this.tamanho -= 1;
}
```

Método de remoção de elemento no início da lista:

```
@Override
public void removeInicio() throws Exception {
    this.verificarSeEstaVazio();
    this.primeira = this.primeira.getProxima();
    this.tamanho -= 1;
    if (this.vazio()) {
        this.ultima = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: O próximo do último é o primeiro.

Comment: Então @Gabriel nesse caso eu teria que implementar nos métodos adicionaFim(E elemento) e removeFim() o comando this.ultima.setProxima(this.primeira)?

Comment: Sim, e ao adicionar ou remover a primeira é preciso atualizar o próximo do último. Em resumo, sempre que mexer nas pontas da lista é preciso atualizar o próximo do último. Também é preciso cuidar quando iterar pelos elementos, pra não entrar em loop infinito.